# create virtual conda env from yaml file on macOs

Tags: python, anaconda

I have a macOS Ventura 13.6.4 MacBook Pro.  I have installed python 3.11.5 using the anaconda installer for macOs.  I am trying to create a conda virtual python environment from a yaml file.  The script I'm running in the terminal is below, along with the yaml file and the error message I'm getting.  Can you please tell me what is causing the error message and how I can modify the yaml file or bash script to avoid the errors.

bash script:

```
conda env create -f llm_110623.yml
```

error message:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - libunistring==0.9.10=h27cfd23_0
  - libstdcxx-ng==11.2.0=h1234567_1
  - tbb==2021.8.0=hdb19cb5_0
  - libopus==1.3.1=h7b6447c_0
  - psutil==5.9.0=py310h5eee18b_0
  - bottleneck==1.3.5=py310ha9d4c09_0
  - tornado==6.2=py310h5eee18b_0
  - abseil-cpp==20211102.0=hd4dd3e8_0
  - networkx==2.8.4=py310h06a4308_1
  - orc==1.7.4=hb3bc3d3_1
  - aws-c-common==0.6.8=h5eee18b_1
  - idna==3.4=py310h06a4308_0
  - libbrotlicommon==1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
  - libvpx==1.7.0=h439df22_0
  - tokenizers==0.13.3=py310h22610ee_0
  - libcusolver==11.4.0.1=0
  - ld_impl_linux-64==2.38=h1181459_1
  - yaml==0.2.5=h7b6447c_0
  - jupyter_core==5.3.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - multidict==6.0.2=py310h5eee18b_0
  - comm==0.1.2=py310h06a4308_0
  - grpc-cpp==1.48.2=he1ff14a_1
  - markupsafe==2.1.1=py310h7f8727e_0
  - frozenlist==1.3.3=py310h5eee18b_0
  - xformers==0.0.19=py310_cu11.8.0_pyt2.0.0
  - gnutls==3.6.15=he1e5248_0
  - jinja2==3.1.2=py310h06a4308_0
  - libgomp==11.2.0=h1234567_1
  - libwebp-base==1.2.4=h5eee18b_1
  - wheel==0.38.4=py310h06a4308_0
  - lz4-c==1.9.4=h6a678d5_0
  - giflib==5.2.1=h5eee18b_3
  - libtiff==4.5.0=h6a678d5_2
  - re2==2022.04.01=h295c915_0
  - sympy==1.11.1=py310h06a4308_0
  - libidn2==2.3.4=h5eee18b_0
  - libgcc-ng==11.2.0=h1234567_1
  - libcurl==8.1.1=h251f7ec_1
  - libgfortran5==11.2.0=h1234567_1
  - chardet==4.0.0=py310h06a4308_1003
  - libwebp==1.2.4=h11a3e52_1
  - zlib==1.2.13=h5eee18b_0
  - libprotobuf==3.20.3=he621ea3_0
  - yarl==1.8.1=py310h5eee18b_0
  - bzip2==1.0.8=h7b6447c_0
  - freetype==2.12.1=h4a9f257_0
  - cuda-cupti==11.7.101=0
  - readline==8.2=h5eee18b_0
  - ffmpeg==4.2.2=h20bf706_0
  - numpy-base==1.25.0=py310hb5e798b_0
  - jedi==0.18.1=py310h06a4308_1
  - cuda-nvrtc==11.7.99=0
  - libcusparse==11.7.4.91=0
  - libsodium==1.0.18=h7b6447c_0
  - xz==5.4.2=h5eee18b_0
  - brotlipy==0.7.0=py310h7f8727e_1002
  - ipykernel==6.19.2=py310h2f386ee_0
  - pillow==9.4.0=py310h6a678d5_0
  - cryptography==41.0.2=py310h22a60cf_0
  - mkl-service==2.4.0=py310h5eee18b_1
  - lcms2==2.12=h3be6417_0
  - colorama==0.4.6=py310h06a4308_0
  - libev==4.33=h7f8727e_1
  - mkl_random==1.2.2=py310h1128e8f_1
  - mpc==1.1.0=h10f8cd9_1
  - aws-c-event-stream==0.1.6=h6a678d5_6
  - pytorch-cuda==11.7=h778d358_5
  - filelock==3.9.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - x264==1!157.20191217=h7b6447c_0
  - arrow-cpp==11.0.0=h374c478_1
  - tqdm==4.65.0=py310h2f386ee_0
  - certifi==2023.7.22=py310h06a4308_0
  - requests==2.31.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - traitlets==5.7.1=py310h06a4308_0
  - libcublas==11.10.3.66=0
  - gmpy2==2.1.2=py310heeb90bb_0
  - cuda-runtime==11.7.1=0
  - krb5==1.20.1=h143b758_1
  - lerc==3.0=h295c915_0
  - intel-openmp==2023.1.0=hdb19cb5_46305
  - libtasn1==4.19.0=h5eee18b_0
  - libboost==1.73.0=h28710b8_12
  - libthrift==0.15.0=h1795dd8_2
  - transformers==4.29.2=py310h06a4308_0
  - libevent==2.1.12=hdbd6064_1
  - libpng==1.6.39=h5eee18b_0
  - attrs==23.1.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - urllib3==1.26.16=py310h06a4308_0
  - xxhash==0.8.0=h7f8727e_3
  - libnghttp2==1.52.0=h2d74bed_1
  - debugpy==1.5.1=py310h295c915_0
  - cuda-libraries==11.7.1=0
  - pandas==2.1.1=py310h1128e8f_0
  - mkl==2023.1.0=h6d00ec8_46342
  - joblib==1.2.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - jpeg==9e=h5eee18b_1
  - nettle==3.7.3=hbbd107a_1
  - aws-checksums==0.1.11=h5eee18b_2
  - aws-sdk-cpp==1.8.185=h721c034_1
  - mkl_fft==1.3.6=py310h1128e8f_1
  - snappy==1.1.9=h295c915_0
  - libffi==3.4.4=h6a678d5_0
  - et_xmlfile==1.1.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - pyopenssl==23.2.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - libgfortran-ng==11.2.0=h00389a5_1
  - mpmath==1.3.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - ncurses==6.4=h6a678d5_0
  - pyzmq==25.1.0=py310h6a678d5_0
  - pandas-stubs==1.5.3.230203=py310h06a4308_0
  - datasets==2.12.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - click==8.1.7=py310h06a4308_0
  - gmp==6.2.1=h295c915_3
  - cudnn==7.6.5=cuda10.1_0
  - huggingface_hub==0.15.1=py310h06a4308_0
  - multiprocess==0.70.14=py310h06a4308_0
  - scikit-learn==1.0.1=py310h00e6091_0
  - sqlite==3.41.2=h5eee18b_0
  - cuda-cudart==11.7.99=0
  - icu==58.2=he6710b0_3
  - packaging==23.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - dill==0.3.6=py310h06a4308_0
  - lame==3.100=h7b6447c_0
  - fsspec==2023.9.2=py310h06a4308_0
  - libbrotlidec==1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
  - openpyxl==3.0.10=py310h5eee18b_0
  - libssh2==1.10.0=hdbd6064_2
  - torchaudio==2.0.0=py310_cu117
  - pygments==2.15.1=py310h06a4308_1
  - pip==23.2.1=py310h06a4308_0
  - numpy==1.25.0=py310h5f9d8c6_0
  - glog==0.5.0=h2531618_0
  - torchvision==0.15.0=py310_cu117
  - jupyter_client==8.1.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - libcurand==10.3.3.53=0
  - libbrotlienc==1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
  - libcufft==10.7.2.124=h4fbf590_0
  - libedit==3.1.20221030=h5eee18b_0
  - c-ares==1.19.0=h5eee18b_0
  - numexpr==2.8.4=py310h85018f9_1
  - pytz==2023.3.post1=py310h06a4308_0
  - pytorch==2.0.0=py3.10_cuda11.7_cudnn8.5.0_0
  - ca-certificates==2023.08.22=h06a4308_0
  - types-pytz==2022.4.0.0=py310h06a4308_1
  - openh264==2.1.1=h4ff587b_0
  - regex==2023.10.3=py310h5eee18b_0
  - zeromq==4.3.4=h2531618_0
  - gflags==2.2.2=he6710b0_0
  - mpfr==4.0.2=hb69a4c5_1
  - _openmp_mutex==5.1=1_gnu
  - libnpp==11.7.4.75=0
  - pyarrow==11.0.0=py310h468efa6_1
  - utf8proc==2.6.1=h27cfd23_0
  - boost-cpp==1.73.0=h7f8727e_12
  - cudatoolkit==10.1.243=h6bb024c_0
  - scipy==1.10.1=py310h5f9d8c6_1
  - libnvjpeg==11.8.0.2=0
  - libdeflate==1.17=h5eee18b_0
  - libuuid==1.41.5=h5eee18b_0
  - pysocks==1.7.1=py310h06a4308_0
  - python-xxhash==2.0.2=py310h5eee18b_1
  - torchtriton==2.0.0=py310
  - zstd==1.5.5=hc292b87_0
  - cuda-nvtx==11.7.91=0
  - cffi==1.15.1=py310h5eee18b_3
  - prompt-toolkit==3.0.36=py310h06a4308_0
  - async-timeout==4.0.2=py310h06a4308_0
  - pyyaml==6.0=py310h5eee18b_1
  - platformdirs==2.5.2=py310h06a4308_0
  - aiohttp==3.8.5=py310h5eee18b_0
  - openssl==3.0.12=h7f8727e_0
  - python==3.10.12=h955ad1f_0
  - ipython==8.12.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - matplotlib-inline==0.1.6=py310h06a4308_0
  - setuptools==68.0.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - libcufile==1.7.0.149=0
  - tk==8.6.12=h1ccaba5_0
```

yaml file llm_110623.yml:

```
name: llm_110623
channels:
  - xformers
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge/label/cf202003
  - nvidia
  - anaconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - _openmp_mutex=5.1=1_gnu
  - abseil-cpp=20211102.0=hd4dd3e8_0
  - aiohttp=3.8.5=py310h5eee18b_0
  - aiosignal=1.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - appdirs=1.4.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - arrow-cpp=11.0.0=h374c478_1
  - asttokens=2.0.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - async-timeout=4.0.2=py310h06a4308_0
  - attrs=23.1.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - aws-c-common=0.6.8=h5eee18b_1
  - aws-c-event-stream=0.1.6=h6a678d5_6
  - aws-checksums=0.1.11=h5eee18b_2
  - aws-sdk-cpp=1.8.185=h721c034_1
  - backcall=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - boost-cpp=1.73.0=h7f8727e_12
  - bottleneck=1.3.5=py310ha9d4c09_0
  - brotlipy=0.7.0=py310h7f8727e_1002
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h7b6447c_0
  - c-ares=1.19.0=h5eee18b_0
  - ca-certificates=2023.08.22=h06a4308_0
  - certifi=2023.7.22=py310h06a4308_0
  - cffi=1.15.1=py310h5eee18b_3
  - chardet=4.0.0=py310h06a4308_1003
  - charset-normalizer=2.0.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - click=8.1.7=py310h06a4308_0
  - colorama=0.4.6=py310h06a4308_0
  - comm=0.1.2=py310h06a4308_0
  - cryptography=41.0.2=py310h22a60cf_0
  - cuda-cudart=11.7.99=0
  - cuda-cupti=11.7.101=0
  - cuda-libraries=11.7.1=0
  - cuda-nvrtc=11.7.99=0
  - cuda-nvtx=11.7.91=0
  - cuda-runtime=11.7.1=0
  - cudatoolkit=10.1.243=h6bb024c_0
  - cudnn=7.6.5=cuda10.1_0
  - datasets=2.12.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - debugpy=1.5.1=py310h295c915_0
  - decorator=5.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - dill=0.3.6=py310h06a4308_0
  - einops=0.2.0=py_0
  - et_xmlfile=1.1.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - executing=0.8.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - ffmpeg=4.2.2=h20bf706_0
  - filelock=3.9.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - freetype=2.12.1=h4a9f257_0
  - frozenlist=1.3.3=py310h5eee18b_0
  - fsspec=2023.9.2=py310h06a4308_0
  - gflags=2.2.2=he6710b0_0
  - giflib=5.2.1=h5eee18b_3
  - glog=0.5.0=h2531618_0
  - gmp=6.2.1=h295c915_3
  - gmpy2=2.1.2=py310heeb90bb_0
  - gnutls=3.6.15=he1e5248_0
  - grpc-cpp=1.48.2=he1ff14a_1
  - huggingface_hub=0.15.1=py310h06a4308_0
  - icu=58.2=he6710b0_3
  - idna=3.4=py310h06a4308_0
  - intel-openmp=2023.1.0=hdb19cb5_46305
  - ipykernel=6.19.2=py310h2f386ee_0
  - ipython=8.12.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - jedi=0.18.1=py310h06a4308_1
  - jinja2=3.1.2=py310h06a4308_0
  - joblib=1.2.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - jpeg=9e=h5eee18b_1
  - jupyter_client=8.1.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - jupyter_core=5.3.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - krb5=1.20.1=h143b758_1
  - lame=3.100=h7b6447c_0
  - lcms2=2.12=h3be6417_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.38=h1181459_1
  - lerc=3.0=h295c915_0
  - libboost=1.73.0=h28710b8_12
  - libbrotlicommon=1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
  - libbrotlidec=1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
  - libbrotlienc=1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
  - libcublas=11.10.3.66=0
  - libcufft=10.7.2.124=h4fbf590_0
  - libcufile=1.7.0.149=0
  - libcurand=10.3.3.53=0
  - libcurl=8.1.1=h251f7ec_1
  - libcusolver=11.4.0.1=0
  - libcusparse=11.7.4.91=0
  - libdeflate=1.17=h5eee18b_0
  - libedit=3.1.20221030=h5eee18b_0
  - libev=4.33=h7f8727e_1
  - libevent=2.1.12=hdbd6064_1
  - libffi=3.4.4=h6a678d5_0
  - libgcc-ng=11.2.0=h1234567_1
  - libgfortran-ng=11.2.0=h00389a5_1
  - libgfortran5=11.2.0=h1234567_1
  - libgomp=11.2.0=h1234567_1
  - libidn2=2.3.4=h5eee18b_0
  - libnghttp2=1.52.0=h2d74bed_1
  - libnpp=11.7.4.75=0
  - libnvjpeg=11.8.0.2=0
  - libopus=1.3.1=h7b6447c_0
  - libpng=1.6.39=h5eee18b_0
  - libprotobuf=3.20.3=he621ea3_0
  - libsodium=1.0.18=h7b6447c_0
  - libssh2=1.10.0=hdbd6064_2
  - libstdcxx-ng=11.2.0=h1234567_1
  - libtasn1=4.19.0=h5eee18b_0
  - libthrift=0.15.0=h1795dd8_2
  - libtiff=4.5.0=h6a678d5_2
  - libunistring=0.9.10=h27cfd23_0
  - libuuid=1.41.5=h5eee18b_0
  - libvpx=1.7.0=h439df22_0
  - libwebp=1.2.4=h11a3e52_1
  - libwebp-base=1.2.4=h5eee18b_1
  - lz4-c=1.9.4=h6a678d5_0
  - markupsafe=2.1.1=py310h7f8727e_0
  - matplotlib-inline=0.1.6=py310h06a4308_0
  - mkl=2023.1.0=h6d00ec8_46342
  - mkl-service=2.4.0=py310h5eee18b_1
  - mkl_fft=1.3.6=py310h1128e8f_1
  - mkl_random=1.2.2=py310h1128e8f_1
  - mpc=1.1.0=h10f8cd9_1
  - mpfr=4.0.2=hb69a4c5_1
  - mpmath=1.3.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - multidict=6.0.2=py310h5eee18b_0
  - multiprocess=0.70.14=py310h06a4308_0
  - ncurses=6.4=h6a678d5_0
  - nettle=3.7.3=hbbd107a_1
  - networkx=2.8.4=py310h06a4308_1
  - numexpr=2.8.4=py310h85018f9_1
  - numpy=1.25.0=py310h5f9d8c6_0
  - numpy-base=1.25.0=py310hb5e798b_0
  - openh264=2.1.1=h4ff587b_0
  - openpyxl=3.0.10=py310h5eee18b_0
  - openssl=3.0.12=h7f8727e_0
  - orc=1.7.4=hb3bc3d3_1
  - packaging=23.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - pandas=2.1.1=py310h1128e8f_0
  - pandas-stubs=1.5.3.230203=py310h06a4308_0
  - parso=0.8.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pexpect=4.8.0=pyhd3eb1b0_3
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=pyhd3eb1b0_1003
  - pillow=9.4.0=py310h6a678d5_0
  - pip=23.2.1=py310h06a4308_0
  - platformdirs=2.5.2=py310h06a4308_0
  - pooch=1.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.36=py310h06a4308_0
  - psutil=5.9.0=py310h5eee18b_0
  - ptyprocess=0.7.0=pyhd3eb1b0_2
  - pure_eval=0.2.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pyarrow=11.0.0=py310h468efa6_1
  - pycparser=2.21=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pygments=2.15.1=py310h06a4308_1
  - pyopenssl=23.2.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=py310h06a4308_0
  - python=3.10.12=h955ad1f_0
  - python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - python-tzdata=2023.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - python-xxhash=2.0.2=py310h5eee18b_1
  - pytorch=2.0.0=py3.10_cuda11.7_cudnn8.5.0_0
  - pytorch-cuda=11.7=h778d358_5
  - pytorch-mutex=1.0=cuda
  - pytz=2023.3.post1=py310h06a4308_0
  - pyyaml=6.0=py310h5eee18b_1
  - pyzmq=25.1.0=py310h6a678d5_0
  - re2=2022.04.01=h295c915_0
  - readline=8.2=h5eee18b_0
  - regex=2023.10.3=py310h5eee18b_0
  - requests=2.31.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - responses=0.13.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - sacremoses=0.0.43=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - scikit-learn=1.0.1=py310h00e6091_0
  - scipy=1.10.1=py310h5f9d8c6_1
  - setuptools=68.0.0=py310h06a4308_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - snappy=1.1.9=h295c915_0
  - sqlite=3.41.2=h5eee18b_0
  - stack_data=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - sympy=1.11.1=py310h06a4308_0
  - tbb=2021.8.0=hdb19cb5_0
  - threadpoolctl=2.2.0=pyh0d69192_0
  - tk=8.6.12=h1ccaba5_0
  - tokenizers=0.13.3=py310h22610ee_0
  - torchaudio=2.0.0=py310_cu117
  - torchtriton=2.0.0=py310
  - torchvision=0.15.0=py310_cu117
  - tornado=6.2=py310h5eee18b_0
  - tqdm=4.65.0=py310h2f386ee_0
  - traitlets=5.7.1=py310h06a4308_0
  - transformers=4.29.2=py310h06a4308_0
  - types-pytz=2022.4.0.0=py310h06a4308_1
  - tzdata=2023c=h04d1e81_0
  - urllib3=1.26.16=py310h06a4308_0
  - utf8proc=2.6.1=h27cfd23_0
  - wcwidth=0.2.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - wheel=0.38.4=py310h06a4308_0
  - x264=1!157.20191217=h7b6447c_0
  - xformers=0.0.19=py310_cu11.8.0_pyt2.0.0
  - xxhash=0.8.0=h7f8727e_3
  - xz=5.4.2=h5eee18b_0
  - yaml=0.2.5=h7b6447c_0
  - yarl=1.8.1=py310h5eee18b_0
  - zeromq=4.3.4=h2531618_0
  - zlib=1.2.13=h5eee18b_0
  - zstd=1.5.5=hc292b87_0
  - pip:
    - absl-py==2.0.0
    - accelerate==0.24.1
    - aiostream==0.5.2
    - annotated-types==0.6.0
    - anyio==3.7.1
    - asgiref==3.7.2
    - backoff==2.2.1
    - bcrypt==4.1.2
    - build==1.0.3
    - cachetools==5.3.2
    - chroma-hnswlib==0.7.3
    - chromadb==0.4.22
    - coloredlogs==15.0.1
    - dataclasses-json==0.5.14
    - deprecated==1.2.14
    - distro==1.8.0
    - evaluate==0.4.0
    - exceptiongroup==1.1.3
    - fastapi==0.109.2
    - flatbuffers==23.5.26
    - google-auth==2.27.0
    - googleapis-common-protos==1.62.0
    - greenlet==3.0.1
    - grpcio==1.60.1
    - h11==0.14.0
    - httpcore==1.0.1
    - httptools==0.6.1
    - httpx==0.25.1
    - humanfriendly==10.0
    - importlib-metadata==6.11.0
    - importlib-resources==6.1.1
    - jsonpatch==1.33
    - jsonpointer==2.4
    - kubernetes==29.0.0
    - langchain==0.0.150
    - langsmith==0.0.60
    - llama-index==0.8.64.post1
    - marshmallow==3.20.1
    - mmh3==4.1.0
    - monotonic==1.6
    - mypy-extensions==1.0.0
    - nest-asyncio==1.5.8
    - nltk==3.8.1
    - oauthlib==3.2.2
    - onnxruntime==1.17.0
    - openai==1.2.1
    - openapi-schema-pydantic==1.2.4
    - opentelemetry-api==1.22.0
    - opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-common==1.22.0
    - opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-grpc==1.22.0
    - opentelemetry-instrumentation==0.43b0
    - opentelemetry-instrumentation-asgi==0.43b0
    - opentelemetry-instrumentation-fastapi==0.43b0
    - opentelemetry-proto==1.22.0
    - opentelemetry-sdk==1.22.0
    - opentelemetry-semantic-conventions==0.43b0
    - opentelemetry-util-http==0.43b0
    - overrides==7.7.0
    - peft==0.3.0
    - posthog==3.4.0
    - protobuf==4.25.2
    - pulsar-client==3.4.0
    - pyasn1==0.5.1
    - pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
    - pydantic==1.10.13
    - pydantic-core==2.10.1
    - pypika==0.48.9
    - pyproject-hooks==1.0.0
    - python-dotenv==1.0.1
    - requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
    - rouge-score==0.1.2
    - rsa==4.9
    - sniffio==1.3.0
    - sqlalchemy==2.0.23
    - starlette==0.36.3
    - tenacity==8.2.3
    - tiktoken==0.5.1
    - tomli==2.0.1
    - trl==0.4.2.dev0
    - typer==0.9.0
    - typing-extensions==4.9.0
    - typing-inspect==0.9.0
    - uvicorn==0.27.0.post1
    - uvloop==0.19.0
    - watchfiles==0.21.0
    - websocket-client==1.7.0
    - websockets==12.0
    - wrapt==1.15.0
    - zipp==3.17.0
prefix: /home/username/anaconda3/envs/llm_110623
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an export of a `conda` virtual environment. What is causing problems is likely (or at least was for me when I tested it on my Windows machine) is the build numbers at the end of the package definition, i.e. "psutil=5.9.0=**py310h5eee18b_0**".

Try re-exporting the original environment with the `--no-build` flag or writing some kind of a parser to get rid of it, so you end up with something like:

```yaml
...
dependencies:
  - python=3.10.12
  - psutil=5.9.0
...
```